# convert html to pdf i angular 5

Tags: unicode, utf-8, angular5, jspdf, farsi

I must be convert html elements to PDF, but I don't want to use html2canvas, because this package convert html image at first, then convert to pdf. this way didn't efficient for my needs.

I used latest version of jspdf ( 1.5.3, that said support built in Unicode and utf-8 characters) with jspdf-autotable.

all things worked, except Persian character that corrupted.
do I must any setting for Unicode characters in last version of jspdf?
I must be use custom font? or default setting built in support Unicode characters?

I read all article about this issue, and run it, but I didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) library for properly export unicode and Persian/Arabic characters.
The html code must be convert to canvas in first step and then convert to pdf.

```
  function export_to_pdf() {
    // Get the element.
    var element = document.getElementById('root');

    // Generate the PDF.
    html2pdf().from(element).set({
      margin: 0,
      filename: 'test.pdf',
      html2canvas: { scale: 1},
      jsPDF: {orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'in', format: 'a4', compressPDF: true}
    }).save();
  }
```